# How do I install heroku on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, aws-cloud9

I am trying to install heroku and for that it says i need to run this:

```
sudo snap install heroku --classic
```

but when i run that i get snap: command not found. when i looked up how to solve this it said i had to do this:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
```

but this does not work as well because it gives this:

```
apt: invalid flag: update
```

What do i do? How do i install heroku on aws cloud 9 linux?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To install heroku on ubuntu,

`curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh`

But, this version does not autoupdate and must be updated manully via apt-get.

Otherwise, to install snap, follow this link: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050388/ubuntu-16-04-install-snapd-problem

Comment: The first curl command returns sh: line 4: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list: No such file or directory

Comment: How about just `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install heroku-toolbelt heroku` without snap

Comment: it says No package heroku-toolbelt available.No package heroku available. I found another way to do it. but im not sure if this works. heroku --version returns heroku/7.29.0 linux-x64 node-v10.16.2           i am working on ruby is this okay?

Comment: Yeah, I think you did it :)

Comment: but it shouldnt it say ruby instead okay of node? will this still function accurately since i am working in ruby environment? thanks for your help!

Comment: No. The Node.js referred to in that message is the version used to build [the Heroku CLI Itself](https://github.com/heroku/cli). It has nothing to do with the language to use in your app.

Comment: @ChanranKim That worked for me finally without toolbelt from cli. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

you are placing the flag "--classic" on the wrong side.

Try this:

```
$ sudo snap install --classic heroku
```

Then check the version using:

```
$ heroku --version
```

Answer (score 4):

To install heroku on ubuntu

> `sudo wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh`

To confirm Horuku is installed, and
setup it with your credentials

`heroku apps`

Comment: This is the only answer that made it work on WSL2

Answer (score 3):

You can simply install using npm:

```
npm install -g heroku
```

Answer (score 0):

Installation instructions can change over time so my recommendation is always consult the official documentation, especially for a security sensitive app like this one.

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#install-the-heroku-cli

Note that you probably want to install their **Standalone Installation** that will auto update to latest version which will ensure you keep up to date with security patches.